# Are there intractable problems?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

Obviously, there is no problem in NP which can be shown to be *intractable* (by which I mean: not in P).

Is there a problem (outside of NP) which can be shown to be intractable (not lying in P)?

Comment: There are a lot of complexity classes outside of NP that should be. . Here is a Complexity Zoo showing which complexity class is subset of which https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/diagram.xml

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_complexity_classes

Comment: [Time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) says yes. EXPTIME-complete problems are an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the [Time Hierarchy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), which broadly speaking states that for any "reasonable" function $f$ there are problems that take about $f(n)$ time to decide.

Concretely, each of the known [EXPTIME-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME) would be an example of something that has been proved not to lie in P.

Here is a [related question on compsci](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/exp-complete-example).

Answer (score -2):

NP-hard / NP. A problem is in NP-hard when every problem L in NP can be reduced in polynomial time to H. Under the assumption of $P \neq NP $ ,NP-hard is intractable. Therefore NP-hard / NP is intractable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness

Comment: I think NP-hard just means "at least as hard as NP."  It does not mean intractable.

Comment: Using definition intractable = not in P. NP hard is not in P, therefore it is intractable

Comment: Please share your proof that NP is not in P with us.

Comment: Care to explain what do u mean @DanielV

Comment: @ClarkMakmur: Your claim that NP-hard problems are automatically not in P is equivalent to asserting that $P\ne NP$, which is an extremely famous _open problem_. The commenters are suggesting that you don't actually know that your claim is true, because _nobody knows what the answer is_, and a working proof of the answer would make its discoverer instantly famous.

Comment: Oh I see the problem, Thanks for the explanation. I will edit the post